# Cant figure out how to solve this probabilty problem?

Tags: probability

So this is the problem:
                       Brittney was packing bags for shipping. As she had reached  bag number 42, she realized that she had an earing missing. What would be the probability that she would find the ring by opening only seven bags?
I can figure that the sample space would have 42 elements, but i cant figure out what number of elements the events set would have.
Thanks.

Comment: **"Reached"** bag 42 is ambiguous. Has she **packed** bag 42 or not ? If not, it is open at this point ....

Comment: well i think i did not check the problem statement again while posting here, and English isnt my first language. So, that might me a mistake by me. And yes she has completed packing bag 42.

Comment: Ok, anyway you have got the desired  response !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although mathbeing's answer is correct, you wanted to identify the sample space so I'll help you with that.

There are probably different ways of setting this up, but for me the most logical way (most connected to reality) is the following. Note that the experiment is taking 7 bags from the collection of 42, and the sample space consists of all those possible outcomes.

If we call the bag with the earring $E$, and enumerate the rest as $N_1, N_2, \ldots, N_{41}$, then the set of bags is

$\mathcal B = \{ E, N_1, N_2, \cdots, N_{41} \}.$

Since the order does not matter and bags are drawn without replacement (and I assume we draw all seven of them before looking at them, instead of drawing them one by one and stopping once we find the earring), an event would be a subset of $\mathcal B$ consisting of seven elements. There are $\binom{42}{7}$ of them in total, all of them either of the form $\{N_{i_1}, N_{i_2}, \ldots, N_{i_7}\}$ or $\{E, N_{i_1}, N_{i_2}, \ldots, L_{i_6}\}$.

How many of the latter type are there, i.e. how many 7-element subsets of the $\binom{42}{7}$ actually contain $E$?

Answer (score 0):

If we have no further information we must assume that the probability that the earing is in each bag is $1/42$. If she opens $7$ bags then the probability of her finding her earing is $$1/42+1/42+1/42+1/42+1/42+1/42+1/42=7/42=1/6\approx 0.167$$